# How to make some buttons of tableView cells clickable and some unclickable | iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios7

I have a tableView in which each cell contains a button with different titles.

[image]

Actually I am passing a titles array to button.
`cell.applyButton.setTitle(titleValues[indexPath.row], for: .normal)`

Now I want to make only those buttons clickable which have title schedule. Please help.

Comment: This sounds data based. So much of your code should be in the table cell - particularly enabling and disabling. But... cell updates are with the data (normally an array) that is maintained elsewhere. Just be sure to call `reloadData` after refreshing the data and you should have it working.

Answer (score 1):

Set the button's `.isEnabled` property, based on the title:

```
cell.applyButton.setTitle(titleValues[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
cell.applyButton.isEnabled = titleValues[indexPath.row] == "Schedule"
```